# UIPageViewController along with UICollectionView for cell grid structure

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uipageviewcontroller, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView`, which uses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to arrange my cells inside the collection view.

Inside my cells, I have an image and a label. Using the above layout I am able to design my collection view with vertical scrolling,

But instead of vertical scrolling, I want a structure like `UIPageViewController` which will contain my `UICollectionView` with the above cells.

I have tried with `flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal`,
But with that approach I could not solve my issue.

I am new to Swift and I am not using storyboards.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found my answer from the below link:
http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/

It really helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: This link is dead

Comment: Next time please post the full answer so we don't rely on the link being maintained

Answer (score 0):

Open your storyboard, select the collectionView and change the scroll direction from vertical to horizontal as shown below :)

[image]

Now your collectionView will start scrolling horizontally than vertically :)

If you want pagination, like ViewControllers in pageViewController, select the collectionView and select paging enabled check box :)

[image]

Now if you want your collection view cell to cover the whole collectionView like view controllers in UIPageViewController, type this in your UICollectionView delegate :)

```
extension YourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return self.pageViewController.frame.size
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

Want to leave spacing between cells return value instead of 0.0 in the above method :) Thats all

**EDIT**

In case you dont have storyboard you can set the scroll direction and other properties programmatically using

```
(self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

Comment: I am not using storyboard in my project. And moreover, my UICollectionView contains more than 1 cell per page. For eg: If my entire array size is 15, based on the screen size, if the 1st page contains 9 items then the rest 6 will be on the 2nd page with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @chittaranjan-sahoo : Can you try my updated answer ??

Comment: I have already tried with (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).scrollDirection = .horizontal
However, it is arranging my cells in vertical order, i.e if I have only 3 items in my array, then instead of placing the 3 items in a row, it is arranging the items in 3 row with 1 column.

Comment: @chittaranjan-sahoo : Tried the code just now. Its working fine, may I know where are you setting the scrollDirection ??

Comment: I am adding this line in the viewDidLoad() of my collection view:   if let flowlayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowlayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal }

Comment: Can you try rather than saying if let directly use (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).scrollDirection = .horizontal on collectionView itself. If it works I'll tell my guess what might be going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129796/discussion-between-chittaranjan-sahoo-and-sandeep-bhandari).